# Function that filters intergers

Tags: python, filter, set, range

Fyi, I'm new to this stuf

So the original question is

7) Write a function filter_range(v, lo, hi) that takes a list v of integers and returns a new list containing only

those elements in v that are within the range [lo, hi).

So I'm having trouble with the concept, if the user inputs the integers and range condition, how will it check all the items in that list individually to that condition or do I have to do a test for each input. Will this be an if statement? If so how would that work? "if a <= str(blah blah) < b then print or something? But how will that print each individual number that passes? Honestly just lost in general, lol

Comment: Clearly homework (just sayin'). Why don't you try __something__ and post it. We'll be happy to guide you from there

Comment: Think about it this way -- If I gave you a deck of cards and asked you to give me all of the numbers from 5 to 9 how would you do it?  You would probably look at each card, decide if it fit in the range and move it to a new pile.  After you've seen all the cards, you would hand me the new pile -- Now try to do that in code.

Comment: Never said it wasn't :)

Comment: I'm my head it goes like v= input('Enter set: ')

a= input('Minimum?: ')

b= input('Maximum?: ')

if a <= v < b:
    print v

Comment: but I know that doesn't work and is prob the wrong way to approach it

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a single line using list comprehensions like this

```
def filter_range(v, lo, hi):
    return [item for item in v if lo <= item < hi]

print filter_range(range(10), 2, 8)
```

**Output**

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: I believe that the notation [lo, high) indicates that lo is to be included, but hi is not.

Comment: @mgilson Yup. Thats how range works. Updated :) Thanks

Comment: What i like about these cool solutions is that even if he give it to his teacher, she'll know that he cheated :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def filter_range(v, lo, hi):
  return list(filter(lambda x: lo<=x<hi, v))
```

OR

```
def filter_range(v, lo, hi):
  acceptable = set(range(lo, hi))
  return list(filter(acceptable.__contains__, v))
```

OR

```
def filter_range(v, lo, hi):
  answer = []
  for i in v:
    if lo <= i < hi:
      answer.append(i)
  return answer
```

OR

```
def filter_range(v, lo, hi):
  answer = []
  for i in v:
    if i >= lo:
      if i < hi:
        answer.append(i)
  return answer
```

Comment: I believe that the notation `[lo, high)` indicates that `lo` is to be included, but `hi` is not.

Comment: @mgilson: good catch! Fixed. Thanks for the bug report

Comment: But how will the user input what hi and lo are, I tried inserting an input question before the if statement but keeps saying unintended block

Comment: @user2994734: You could call the function by `filter_range(int(input("Enter v: ")), int(input("Enter lo: ")), int(input("Enter hi: ")))`

Answer (score 0):

In Python3 it's fairly efficient (doesn't actually create a list and scan it) to use.

```
def filter_range(v, lo, hi):
    return [i for i in v if i in range(lo, hi)]
```

In Python2 you should use `xrange` instead of `range`